# Access 2013 vba - clear a form's controls, bypassing calculated controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I would like to clear all the controls in an Access 2013 form.  I found the following script on this site by Johan Godfried and it works very well.

```
Private Sub resetForm()

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctl)
        Case "TextBox"
            ctl.value = ""
        Case "CheckBox", "ToggleButton"
            ctl.value = False
        Case "OptionGroup"
            ctl = Null
        Case "OptionButton"
            ' Do not reset an optionbutton if it is part of an OptionGroup
            If TypeName(ctl.Parent) <> "OptionGroup" Then ctl.value = False
        Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
            ctl.RowSource = vbNullString
    End Select
    Next ctl
 End Sub
```

Except that when the iteration selects a calculated control I receive the following error:
**You can't assign a value to this object**.

Is there a property that can be used to by-pass calculated controls?

Comment: What do you have as the Control Source property for those controls you wish to clear?  Is Control Source blank for those target controls?

Answer (score 0):

try `Me.myControl.controlsource=""` to unbound that control

and then call `resetForm()`